# Поиск и удаление архивных файлов в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

Дано: архивные файлы в директории, ОС Linux

Найти: все файлы которые внутри содержат определенное значение и удалить их

Нахожу файлы вот такой командой:

```
find /путь -type -f -name "*" -ctime +0 -exec zgrep -i 'текст123' {} \;
```

Вопрос, как корректно суда добавить удаление таких файлов? (вначале ищем нужные потом удаляем) Или может быть вообще по другому все переписать.

Answer (score 5):

> Вопрос, как корректно суда добавить удаление таких файлов? (вначале ищем нужные потом удаляем)

`find` — простая утилита... нужно удалить найденные файлы — можно просто добавить `-delete`:

```
find /путь -type -f -name "*" -ctime +0 -exec zgrep -i 'текст123' {} \; -delete
```

---

**Как это работает**

`-exec ... {} \;` является не только *действием*, но и *тестом*, таким же как `-name` или `-ctime`: он считается успешным, если вызываемая программа вернула код корректного завершения, т.е. ноль; а `zgrep` (как и `grep`) возвращает ноль, когда в переданном ему файле найдено хоть одно совпадение.

Чтобы вывод был менее грязным/более полезным можно передать ключик `-q` `zgrep`'у, дабы он перестал выводить найденные строки и `-print`, `find`'у, чтобы выводить имена удаляемых файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проверку условия в ключе `exec`:

```
find /путь -type -f -ctime +0 -exec sh -c "if test zgrep -iq 'текст123' {}; then rm -f {}; fi" \;
```

В данном случае `sh -c "if test zgrep -iq 'текст123' {}; then rm -f {}; fi" \;` - вызов оператора сравнения if в отдельной оболочке shell

Не забудьте предварительно протестировать

Comment: `test` — явно лишний... а ещё при таком подходе будут проблемы с обработкой файлов с пробелами в именах...